# Cast all members of an std::vector

Tags: c++, c++11, casting

```
class A {};
class B : public A {};
std::vector<A*> v;
// populate the vector via library api
// now I need it cast to std::vector<B*>
```

Cast the whole thing works:

```
auto vv = reinterpret_cast< std::vector<B*>& >(v)
```

Is there a way to avoid the unsafe cast - std::move, placement new, something?

Comment: first, how can you know that each `A*` is `B*` ?

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki, excellent question. Here is my comment in the codebase, explaining it. This is a refactoring action. `// I do not know why we assume all A pointers are also B pointers, but that's how it was implemented previously and I am keeping it that way.`

Comment: Is the vector so huge that you won't risk making a copy ? (it stores only pointers)

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki, I would need to declare `std::vector<B*>` and loop over `v`, casting each element and pushing it to the second one, correct? This also has it's downsides. The posted solution appears to work, but I am asking this question to know for the future - this seems a common case.

Comment: Instead of a potentially unsafe reinterpret_cast, I would create my own vector_wrapper class that takes the original vector by reference and provides a similar API that internally does the casting. (Assuming you don't actually need a vector<B>, but only want to use its methods.)

Comment: _why_ do you need to cast the vector to `vector<B*>`? Why can't you just cast each element that you pull out of the vector, as you pull it out?

Comment: Note that the `reinterpret_cast` **will always fail** if the conversion from `A*` to `B*` requires a pointer adjustment, regardless of compiler. E.g. this fails if `A` is not the first base class of `B`. A normal element-wise cast **will** work in those situations.

Answer (score 2):

Since you don't know if the `A`s in the original vector can be cast to `B`s. Then you could use a raw loop and check with `dynamic_cast` each element if is convertible to `B` and thus populate your vector only with the "safe" elements:

```
for(auto &&e : v) {
  auto p = dynamic_cast<B*>(e);
  if(p) vv.push_back(p);
}
```

Alternatively, you could use the following template that transforms a range of arbitrary `A`s to a range of arbitrary `B`s, without worrying if in the ranges of `A`s there are `A`s that can't be transformed to `B`:

```
template<typename C, typename InputIterator, typename OutputIterator>
std::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of<std::remove_pointer_t<typename std::iterator_traits<InputIterator>::value_type>, 
  std::remove_pointer_t<C>>::value> 
cast_range(InputIterator first, InputIterator last, OutputIterator out) {
  while(first != last) {
    auto p = dynamic_cast<std::remove_pointer_t<C>*>(*first);
    if(p) *out = p;
    ++first;
  }
}
```

[**Live Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ab670d265db990f5)

Comment: Would be simpler with `auto p = dynamic_cast< ...`

Comment: @MSalters Thanxs, I've altered to your suggestion.